# Wrong default system encoding detected in Java application

Tags: python, java, windows, encoding, cp1250

### What is the problem?

I've noticed a strange problem with Java showing different default file encodings while running at the same machine and OS (Windows 10). If I run my Gradle application from a console, `Charset.defaultCharset()` shows `Windows-1250`. When I run it from IntelliJ (also as Gradle app) it shows `Windows-1252`.

It is even more strange when I run it on a different computer with Windows 11 - the results are quite opposite, `Windows-1252` while running from a console and `Windows-1250` in IntelliJ.

The correct system encoding for my OS (Polish version of Win 10/11) should always be `Windows-1250` as far as I know.

I use AdoptOpenJDK 16, Gradle 7.0 and IJ 2021.3.2.

### Why is it important in my case?

My Java application executes external Python scripts and communicates with Python processes created by `ProcessBuilder` via `Process.getInput/OutputStream()`. When I send some data with non-ascii characters through that stream, they are replaced with `?` and read as such on the Python side. For example, on Java side I am sending a line like this:

```java
try (var inputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(scriptProcess.getOutputStream()))) {
    inputWriter.write("Właściciel");
}
```

and on the Python side I am receiving this data like this:

```py
inputBuffer = []
for line in stdin:
    inputBuffer.append(line.rstrip())
```

When I print `inputBuffer` or write it to a file, it shows `W?a?ciciel`. It's worth noting that this behavior doesn't depend on the encoding of the input string itself - "Właściciel" can be read from UTF-8 or Windows-1250 or Windows-1252 file and the problem remains the same.

If I force a correct encoding by adding it as a Writer's parametr:

```java
var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(scriptProcess.getOutputStream(), "Windows-1250")
```

..then it works ok, question marks disappear. But I feel hardcoding "system encoding" is not a good solution, because it will collapse if someone runs my app on Windows with other regional settings (e.g. with the English language, where default encoding is UTF-8).

**So my question is:** is there another way to determine valid system encoding or to create communication between processes that is independent of system encoding/region settings?

Comment: If no argument is given, the platform default encoding should be used

Comment: I know, but the whole point of this problem is that default platform encoding is wrong (Windows-1252 instead of Windows-1250) which leads to non-ascii characters being replaced with '?'.

Comment: OK, I see. Let's look at this: *When I send some data with non-ascii characters through that stream, they are replaced with ?* Please give us an example of something causing this problem then we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Ok, I added a more detailed example to my post.

Comment: *inputWriter.write("Właściciel");* OK, the first thing to say about that is that it won't encode in WIndows-1252 at all. It has to be Windows-1250. So where the *effective* default encoding is W-1252, it's going to fail with the tell-tale question marks appearing. What's that's saying effectively is "my character set can't encode those characters"